# Access Model object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model, `Customers`, in which I have a list property, `PayHistory`. I need to bind the table with the `PayHistory` object using jQuery in my ASP.NET MVC (C#) application.

I am binding the table using jQuery as:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="PaidDate">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="PaidAmt">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //Initialize the dynamic Value;
      _dynId = 1;
      var data= '<%= Model.PayHistory %>';
       if (data != null) {
            for (i in data) {
                var pay= data[i];
                $('#PaidDate').append('<div id="PaidDate' + _dynId  + '" style="height:20px;padding-left:10px;">' + '<label>' + pay.paidDate+ '</label>');
                $('#PaidAmt').append('<div id="PaidAmt' + _dynId  + '" style="height:20px;padding-left:10px;">' + '<label>' + pay.PaidAmount + '</label>');
                _dynId   += 1;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the above HTML, I am trying to access the list object `PayHistory` in jQuery, but it gives the type of the object.

How can I access the object in jQuery to bind the table as in the HTML given above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do a bit more work to get the data into a form that JavaScript can understand. The easiest way is to encode the data in the object as a [JSON string](http://www.json.org/), then emit that to the `data` variable instead.

You can do this manually (by creating a method of the class that does this) or since you are using ASP.NET MVC you can use the [Json method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json.aspx). However, this will have to be done in the Controller instead of the View. So, I would add it to your Model object or in the generic View Data. It can probably exist as a property of the Model object that just calls the Json method on the original value and returns it.

**C#**

```
public string JsonPayHistory
{
    get 
    {
        return Json(PayHistory);
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var data = '<%= Model.JsonPayHistory %>';
```

You will want to take a look at the string that is returned. It will be in the JSON format and will have to be evaluated. You can do this by adding:

```
data = eval(data); // usually a bad idea
```

or

```
data = JSON.parse(data); // may require a library if browser doesn't support it
```

Now, you should have an object that is similar to your C# object. You can loop over it and reference properties by name. If you provide the basic structure of your PayHistory object, I can give better examples.

Comment: I am getting an error: The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context. When i used var data = '<%= Json(Model.PayHistory) %>'; Do i need to add any reference here?

Comment: It looks like you will have to move this Json call to the controller. It's not allowed to be used in the view due to its protection level. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: +1, you could also try `var data = <%= Model.JsonPayHistory %>;` and skip the eval.

Comment: it says, "The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context". I have also tried with ViewData as  ViewData["PayHistory"] = Json(customer.PayHistory);

But it returns the type only in jquery assignment.

Comment: referred the answers from @EndangeredMassa and @takepara to get the desired result.

Comment: I'm not sure why your project didn't work with the Json method. I tested it in MVC2, which may be the issue. But, I'm glad that you found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data= <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.PayHistory) %>;
```

Comment: is there any easiest jquery option to read serialized object? I need to bind the values to a div by reading the json..

Comment: Got the answer..
var data= <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.PayHistory) %>;
var payhistory = eval(data);

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for various conversions between .NET objects and classes and JSON.